# Entity Framework reference property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working with Entity Framework 6.

I am working with 2 classes:

```
public partial class StateProvince
{

     public StateProvince()
    {
        Addresses = new HashSet<Address>();
    }

    public int StateProvinceID { get; set; }

    public string StateProvinceCode { get; set; }

    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }

    public bool IsOnlyStateProvinceFlag { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int TerritoryID { get; set; }

    public Guid rowguid { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    public CountryRegion CountryRegion { get; set; }

}

public partial class CountryRegion
{
    public CountryRegion()
    {
        StateProvinces = new HashSet<StateProvinceTlb>();
    }

    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set;}
}
```

I would like to be able to run a query that would return a list of StateProvince, but also include the name from CountryRegion. The idea is that on an edit screen, the user will select, or edit the CountryRegionCode, but the Name will display beside it in a none editable field just for reference.

I tried adding property as a none mapped field to StateProvince and referencing the property on CountryRegion, like below:

```
    [NotMapped]
    public string CountryName
    {
        get{ return CountryRegion.Name;}
    }
```

but the problem with this is the CountryRegion has to be loaded in order for that to work, and my goal is to not have to load the entire CountryRegion object.

I've also tried to set it in my query like this:

```
            List<StateProvince> statP = context.StateProvinces.Select(s => new StateProvince() {s, CountryName = context.CountryRegions.Where(x => x.CountryRegionCode == s.CountryRegionCode).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

but this doesn't work because the object returned is comprised of a StateProvince object and a separate CountryName property.

I've even tried setting each of the fields individually like:

```
            List<StateProvince> statP = context.StateProvinces.Select(s => new StateProvince() { Name = s.Name, TerritoryID = s.TerritoryID, rowguid = s.rowguid, ModifiedDate = s.ModifiedDate, Addresses=s.Addresses, CountryRegion=s.CountryRegion, CountryName = context.CountryRegions.Where(x => x.CountryRegionCode == s.CountryRegionCode).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault() }).ToList();
```

But this again causes the entire CountryRegion object to load, and if I leave those properties out, an exception is thrown. Also, for larger entities this will be hard to maintain.

The TLDR; version of this: Is there a way in Entity Frameworks to have a class mapped to one table, but have a property on that class that references a property on another table without having to retrieve everything on the child table?

I've searched and searched and can't really find much covering this specific kinda of scenario. I'm fairly new to Entity Framework, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

**SOLUTION**

This is what I've come up with to solve the issue.

First, I split the CountryRegion table into two separate classes

```
public partial class CountryRegionHeader
{
    public CountryRegionHeader()
    {
       StateProvinces = new HashSet<StateProvinceTlb>();
    }

    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class CountryRegionDetail
{
    public CountryRegionDetail()
    {
        StateProvinces = new HashSet<StateProvinceTlb>();
    }

    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }


    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set;}

    public virtual CountryRegion CountryRegion {get;set;}

}
```

I then add the properties for the new classes to my StateProvince class

```
[ForeignKey("CountryRegionCode)]
public CountryRegionHeader CountryRegionHeader {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("CountryRegionCode)]
public CountryRegionDetail CountryRegionDetail {get;set;}
```

I then add the DBSets to my model context for CountryRegionHeader and CountryRegionDetail and  tie them together using the fluent API in the OnModelCreating method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CountryRegionHeader>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.CountryRegionDetail)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
}
```

In addition to this, I've created another class just called CountryRegion which has all of the properties from both the Header and Detail as well as the Header and Detail object themselves. The properties actually point back to the header and detail. This really isn't necessary, but it makes the code cleaner and easier to use. Also, when sending the data down to a web client I can just serialize the CountryRegion object and exclude the Header and Detail object. So basically my  CountryRegion class looks like this:

```
public Class CountryRegion
{
    public CountryRegionHeader Header;
    public CountryRegionDetail Detail;

    public CountryRegionCode
    {
       //need some special logic here for the key since both Header or
       //Detail share the primary key and both may not be loaded
       get
       {
           if (Header != null)
               return Header.CountryRegionCode;
           else
               return Detail.CountryRegionCode; 
        }
        set
        {
            if (Header != null) Header.CountryRegionCode = value;
            if (Detail != null) Detail.CountryRegionCode = value;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return Header.Name;
        }
        set
        {
            Header.Name = value;
        }

    }

    public DateTime ModifiedDate
    {
        get
        {
            return Detail.ModifiedDate ;
        }
        set
        {
            Detail.ModifiedDate = value;
        }

    }

    public virtual ICollection<StateProvince> StateProvinces
    {
        get
        {
            return Detail.StateProvinces ;
        }
        set
        {
            Detail.StateProvinces = value;
        }

    }

}
```

So, Now When I query I can do something like:

```
List<StateProvince> query =       db.StateProvince.Include(o=>o.CountryRegionHeader).ToList();
```

And I only retrieve the data I need without retrieving the entire CountryRegion record

Also, If I'm working with just the CountryRegion, I can query like this:

```
List<CountryRegion> query = (from a in db.CountryRegionHeader join b in    db.CountryRegionDetail on a.CountryRegionCode equals b.CountryRegionCode select new Employee(){Header = a, Detail = b}).ToList();
```

Comment: Which EF workflow do you use (Code First, Database First) ?

Comment: Code first with an existing database.

Comment: Glad you found a solution to this. You should post your solution as an answer and mark accept it. That will bring more clarity to someone who ran into your issue and found this post.

Comment: Thanks Ermiar, I appreciate your input on this issue!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLUTION

This is what I've come up with to solve the issue.

First, I split the CountryRegion table into two separate classes

```
public partial class CountryRegionHeader
{
    public CountryRegionHeader()
    {
       StateProvinces = new HashSet<StateProvinceTlb>();
    }

    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class CountryRegionDetail
{
    public CountryRegionDetail()
    {
        StateProvinces = new HashSet<StateProvinceTlb>();
    }

    public string CountryRegionCode { get; set; }


    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set;}

    pubic virtual CountryRegion CountryRegion {get;set;}

}
```

I then add the properties for the new classes to my StateProvince class

```
[ForeignKey("CountryRegionCode)]
public CountryRegionHeader CountryRegionHeader {get;set;}

[ForeignKey("CountryRegionCode)]
public CountryRegionDetail CountryRegionDetail {get;set;}
```

I then add the DBSets to my model context for CountryRegionHeader and CountryRegionDetail and tie them together using the fluent API in the OnModelCreating method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<CountryRegionHeader>()
        .HasRequired(e => e.CountryRegionDetail)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal();
}
```

In addition to this, I've created another class just called CountryRegion          which has all of the properties from both the Header and Detail as well as the Header and Detail object themselves. The properties actually point back to the header and detail. This really isn't necessary, but it makes the code cleaner and easier to use. Also, when sending the data down to a web client I can just serialize the CountryRegion object and exclude the Header and Detail object. So basically my CountryRegion class looks like this:

```
public Class CountryRegion
{
    public CountryRegionHeader Header;
    public CountryRegionDetail Detail;

    public CountryRegionCode
    {
       //need some special logic here for the key since both Header or
       //Detail share the primary key and both may not be loaded
       get
       {
           if (Header != null)
               return Header.CountryRegionCode;
           else
               return Detail.CountryRegionCode; 
       }
       set
       {
           if (Header != null) Header.CountryRegionCode = value;
           if (Detail != null) Detail.CountryRegionCode = value;
       }
   }

   public string Name
   {
       get
       {
           return Header.Name;
       }
       set
       {
           Header.Name = value;
       }

   }

   public DateTime ModifiedDate
   {
       get
       {
            return Detail.ModifiedDate ;
       }
       set
       {
            Detail.ModifiedDate = value;
       }

   }

   public virtual ICollection<StateProvince> StateProvinces
   {
      get
      {
           return Detail.StateProvinces ;
      }
      set
      {
           Detail.StateProvinces = value;
      }

   }

}
```

So, Now When I query I can do something like:

```
List<StateProvince> query =       db.StateProvince.Include(o=>o.CountryRegionHeader).ToList();
```

And I only retrieve the data I need without retrieving the entire CountryRegion record

Also, If I'm working with just the CountryRegion, I can query like this:

```
List<CountryRegion> query = (from a in db.CountryRegionHeader join b in    db.CountryRegionDetail on a.CountryRegionCode equals b.CountryRegionCode select new Employee(){Header = a, Detail = b}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to add a computed column on your database that gives you the CountryRegion name on your StateProvince.

With this all you have to do is to request the StateProvince table and your database server will give you the relevant associated CountryRegion name.

**Edit**

After your comment I had another idea.

Create a class for your usage :

```
public class StateProvinceEdition : StateProvince
{
    public string CountryRegionName { get; set; }

    public StateProvinceEdition(StateProvince stateProvince, string countryRegionName)
    {
        this.StateProvinceID = stateProvince.StateProvinceID;
        // And so on ...

        // Adding country region name
        this.CountryRegionName = countryRegionName;
    }
}
```

Then you need to project your query result into your object using Linq :

```
 List<StateProvinceEdition> statP = context.StateProvinces.Select(s => new StateProvince(s, s.CountryRegion.Name)).ToList();
```

I do not have a database to test it upon so if EF throws an exception regarding the constructor, try to switch the Select and ToList statements to first load objects from the database and then project the result in the custom class.

**Second edit**

Similar to the first idea, you can create a view in your database for your purpose and then use Entity Framework to query this view. With this solution you do not need to change your database other than adding a view.

Comment: Hmmm, as a last resort that may work, but this needs to work with Oracle and SQL Server without affecting other application tied to the same database. I would really like to find a solution that didn't involve modifying the database itself. But it is a good suggestion.

Comment: @BrettKersey I came up with another potential solution, please see my edited post.

Comment: I had attempted a similar approach, unfortunately it does cause an exception about the constructor. And moving it after the ToList() and referencing it like: new StateProvince(s, s.CountryRegion.Name) requires s.CountryRegion to be loaded, so it kinda defeats the purpose. Also tried adding another Lambda expression instead of s.CountryRegion.Name but of course that translate to a separate query for each record that was originally returned. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @BrettKersey Okay. The other solution is to initialize each field explicitly but  that is identical to the second Linq query you tried in your question. I'm afraid you cannot go around the fact to load the related entity for your need.
Another question : why do you not want to load the CompanyRegion object ? It does not seems to have "heavy" properties you'll want to avoid for performance reasons.

Comment: In this instance it's not heavy, but this is just a simple scenario I mocked up to see if I could get it to work. Real world case would be a db with a much larger tables and multiple FK relationships per table. In addition this will be for a web app. I'm just trying to be economical with loading and sending data for performance. I was just hoping there was a straightforward approach to handling this.

Comment: @BrettKersey Lazy loading on EF will mitigate performances issue in a web application : you will only query related table when needed. I thought of another solution that will require to change your database but not adding another column (see second edit in my answer).

Comment: I believe I came up with a solution, I've posted an update to my original message. Thanks!