# EntityFramework Core 2.2 to 3.1.1 Got error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I just finished upgrade my .net core 2.2 to 3.1.101
When I run (dotnet run) I got this error on my controllers

> Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation
>   property 'UserAssignment.Appointee' of type 'User'. Either manually
>   configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the
>   '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.

Let me explain the relationship first, a User can have many UserAssignment, each UserAssignment
can have Appointee and Manager (which is other User).

UserAssignment

```
namespace CRSApp.API.Models
{
    public class UserAssignment
    {
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate {get; set;}
        public bool IsPersonalInsolvency { get; set; }
        public bool IsCorporateInsolvency { get; set; }
        public int? AppointeeId { get; set; }
        public User Appointee { get; set; }
        public int? ManagerId { get; set; }
        public User Manager { get; set; }
        public int? StaffDefaultRateId {get; set;}
        public StaffDefaultRate StaffDefaultRate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

User.cs

```
public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
            public string Username { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "blob")]
            public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "blob")]
            public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
            public string LastName { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
            public string MiddleName { get; set; }

            [Column(TypeName = "varchar(200)")]
            public string Email { get; set; }       
            public string MobileNumber { get; set; }       

            public ICollection<UserAssignment> Assignments {get; set;}

        }
```

the DbContext model builder :

```
    builder.Entity<UserAssignment>().HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.StaffDefaultRateId});
    builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
        .HasOne( x => x.User)
        .WithMany(y => y.Assignments)
        .HasForeignKey( x => x.UserId);
    builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
        .HasOne( x => x.StaffDefaultRate)
        .WithMany( y => y.Assignments)
        .HasForeignKey( x => x.StaffDefaultRateId);
```

Please help me how to solve this problem ? as in the previous ef core 2.2, this code work fine.

Comment: Just because I'm not sure about it either: Is it possible you need to create a new migration? Maybe save up the old one and start a new migration. If that's no issue with alternating EF Core versions, forget this.

Comment: Does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35984325/entity-framework-reference-property?

Comment: What is the intent of `public ICollection<UserAssignment> Assignments {get; set;}` considering there are actually two relationships (as Manager and as Appointee)?  Did you want that to be a navigation property, and if so, back to which foreign key?

Comment: Nevermind, I see that it should probably be assignments the User made, not ones they were the manager or appointee for.  By the way, what is the primary key of the UserAssignment table?  I don't see an obvious one in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently bug (something has been broken while fixing something else).

Looks like having two not explicitly mapped reference navigation properties to `User` (`Manager` and `Appointee`) is confusing EF Core 3.1 conventional relationship mapper.

Adding

```
builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Appointee);
```

or

```
builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Manager);
```

will fix it, but to avoid future issues like this, I would suggest explicitly mapping at least the intended relationship navigation properties:

```
builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Appointee)
    .WithMany();
builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Manager)
    .WithMany();
```

Comment: `.WithMany()` with no parameters will cause no reciprocal navigation property from User back to UserAssignment.  Was that the intention?

Comment: @pseudocoder Every collection can be mapped only to one inverse navigation. The `user.UserAssignments` collection will contain only the items with `User == user`. Your `User` class has no collection properties for `Manager == user` or `Appointee == user`, hence the fluent API is just that  - saying that the property has no inverse collection property. If you add `ManagerAssignments` or `AppointeeAssignments`, then specify them inside the corresponding `WithMany()`. The answer is based on your current model and how it was mapped by EF Core 2.x

Comment: Well, it's not my model, but OK I get it!

Answer (score 2):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#conventions

According to the conventions, your code is correct.

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/13274#issuecomment-420322267

The convention is used only on entities in the context.
Add `DbSet<UserAssignment>` in your context can work.

Or you can specify the foreign key :

```cs
builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
    .HasOne( x => x.Appointee)
    .HasForeignKey( x => x.AppointeeId);
builder.Entity<UserAssignment>()
    .HasOne( x => x.Manager)
    .HasForeignKey( x => x.ManagerId);
```

Comment: I think there is a bug in 3.1.1 github that sometimes relationships are not recognized. Remember seeing something there.

Comment: `.HasOne(...).HasForeignKey(...)` shouldn't work.  You need to throw a `.WithMany(...)` in there I think.